# Night Mode using CSS and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I just added a new feature to my portfolio: Night Mode. I created it with CSS and session storage in JavaScript. I want you to review my CSS of night files, I feel it's filled with `!important` and I'm sure this is a bad practice. Can anyone help me make them better?

My second question, the default mode (white mode) runs in the first milliseconds when moving from page to another. I think it's not a good practice. Can anyone help me make it better?

[Live](https://zeyadetman.github.io/): just set the session to night using this JavaScript line `sessionStorage.setItem("mode", "night");` and refresh.

[Alll files.](https://github.com/zeyadetman/zeyadetman.github.io)

CSS files:

```css
body{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
.indx-contnt p {
    color: white !important;
}
.signature span, a {
    color: white;
}
h1{
    color:#f90 !important;
}
.latest li span{
    color: black !important;
}
.latest li a{
    color:white !important;
}

.contentlist li:nth-child(2) a{
    color:#2CAAE1 !important;
}

.contentlist li:nth-child(3) a{
    color:#0177B5 !important;
}

.contentlist li:nth-child(1) a{
    color:#717171 !important;
}

#rss{
    background-color: black;
}

.signature span, a{
    color: white !important;
}
.latest li a:hover {
    color: #f90 !important;
}

p, h1, h2,h4,span{
    color: white;
}
```

```css
body{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
.signature span, a{
    color: white !important;
}
p, h1, h2, h4, span {
    color: white !important;
}
.project span {
    color: black !important;
}
.card{
    background-color: #ffffff0f !important;
}
.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 10px 7px 10px 0px rgb(255, 153, 0) !important;
}
.card a{
    background-color: black !important;
}

#rss{
    background-color: black !important;
}

.card-title{
    color: #f90 !important; 
}

.posts a {
    color: white !important;
}
```

Comment: You have quite a few elements where you specify only one of background and foreground - that can interact very badly with the user's stylesheet (e.g. your `p { color: white !important; }` when user has `p { background-color: white; color: black; }`).

Answer (score 3):

I like the idea you have here and the implementation looks good.  You are right though that it is not best practice to use `!important` frequently.

I'd think you could avoid using `!important`s simply with either of the following:

- Order: having night mode CSS come later/below day mode CSS
- [Specificity](https://codepen.io/LouBagel/pen/eajNoO): as in `div.nightmode` or `.nightmode div` would override just `div`.

Below I used specificity as the order was more to keep it organized.  Sorry I didn't revise your code but I wanted to test this out for myself and see if my simple idea would work.

### Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Night Mode Test</title>
    <style media="screen">
body, div, h1, p, button{
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

body{
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column nowrap;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;

        padding: 30px;
      }

      div{
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px gray;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 15px;
      }

      button{
        background: green;
        color: white;
        padding: 1em 3em;
        border-radius: 10px;
        margin: 50px;
        outline: 0;
        border: 0;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        cursor: pointer;
      }


      .nightMode button{
        background: white;
        color: green;
      }

      .nightMode{
        background: black;
      }

      .nightMode div{
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px gold;
      }

      .nightMode h1, .nightMode p{
        color: white;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="">
      <h1>Some Sample Stuff</h1>
      <p>Sample Text...</p>
    </div>

    <button id="toggleNightMode" type="button" name="button">Toggle</button>



  <script type="text/javascript">
    const button = document.getElementById('toggleNightMode');
    button.addEventListener('click', function(event){
      if(document.body.classList.contains('nightMode')) document.body.classList.remove('nightMode');
      else document.body.classList.add('nightMode');
    });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So I'd recommend doing the following:

- Combine some of your CSS that uses the same color and/or background
- Use specificity to override CSS instead of `!important`s.  I'd recommend using a class or two (`dayMode`, `nightMode`).  My small example only needed one: if it lacked the `nightMode` class then I knew it was day mode.

[CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/LouBagel/pen/eajNoO)